# Docker Compose: Accessing my webapp from the browser

Tags: node.js, deployment, docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

I'm finding the docs sorely lacking for this (or, I'm dumb), but here's my setup:

Webapp is running on `Node` and `Express`, in `port 8080`. It also connects with a MongoDB container (hence why I'm using `docker-compose`).

In my Dockerfile, I have:

```
FROM node:4.2.4-wheezy

# Set correct environment variables.
ENV HOME /root

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install;

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD ["node", "app.js"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

I run:

```
docker-compose build web
docker-compose build db
docker-compose up -d db
docker-compose up -d web
```

When I run `docker-machine ip default` I get `192.168.99.100`.

So when I go to `192.168.99.100:8080` in my browser, I would *expect* to see my app - but I get connection refused.

What silly thing have I done wrong here?

Comment: can you share your _docker-compose.yml_ file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fairly new here as well, but did you publish your ports on your docker-compose file?

Your Dockerfile will simply expose the ports but not open access to your host. Publishing (with the -p flag on a `docker run` command or `ports` on a docker-compose file. Will enable access from outside the container (see [ports in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/))
Something like this may help:

```
ports:
  - "8080:8080"
```

Comment: Ah, as with all things I've found with Docker, one simple line solves all my problems. Thanks mate!